# Dynamically-generated Mocha tests not executing in async/await context

Tags: node.js, for-loop, mocha.js

I am unable to get my Mocha tests to run. Part of what I need to test against I fetch in an asynchronous manner (from remote server), returned by my `getStatus()` function (replaced by a timeout for simplicity). I have a similar code sample without async/await which works fine (can provide a repl.it as well if needed).

**Simplified code** (you can play with it [here on repl.it](https://repl.it/@montrealist/mocha-async)):

```
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

const getStatus = async function() {
    await sleep(1000);
    return 2;
};

describe('main describe', async function () {
    let uids = [1,2,3];

    describe('Tha test!', async function () {
        console.info('started describe() block...');

        let outcome;
        let status;

        const callback = function () {
            console.info(`inside callback, status is ${status} and outcome is ${outcome}`);
            expect(status).to.equal(outcome);
        };

        for(let uid in uids) {
            status = await getStatus(uids[uid]);
            console.info('the status returned by getStatus is:', status);
            it(`The status for ${uids[uid]} should be ${outcome}`, callback);
        }
    });
});
```

*Note: the callback inside the it() clause was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101792/using-a-for-loop-in-a-mocha-test).*

**Output:**

```
started describe() block...

  0 passing (0ms)

the status returned by getStatus is: 2
the status returned by getStatus is: 2
the status returned by getStatus is: 2
```

**Expected output:**

```
started describe() block...

the status returned by getStatus is: 2
the status returned by getStatus is: 2
the status returned by getStatus is: 2

      1) number 0 should equal 2
      2) number 1 should equal 2
      ✓ number 2 should equal 2

  1 passing (11ms)
  2 failing
```

**Question:** why are my `it()` clauses not executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you cannot pass an `async` callback into a `describe()`. Who knew.

So here's how it should be done in order for all the async stuff to work:

```
describe('do not put async before the function keyword!', function () {
    uids = process.env.ENV_OBJECTS.split(',');

    let outcome;

    for(let uid in uids) {
        it('Can safely put async before the function here', async function() {
            outcome = await getOutcome(uid);
            // etc.
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to address a similar issue which might be one level of complexity above. In my scenario, I need to first asynchronously get the reference data to drive the loop.